# how to use the if statement for error and warning messages in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing my codes on gedit and I want to get the latest error and warning messages using if statement, if theres an error then I should get a warning messages.

```
cp /Volumes/Documents/criticalfile.txt /Volumes/BackUp/. 
if [ "?" != 0 ]; then 
    echo "[Error] copy failed!" 1>&2 
    exit 1 
fi
```

I've used the above code but I am not sure if its correct or not.

Comment: it's `if [ $? != 0 ] ...`. But really you can do `if ! cp /Vols/Docs/File.txt /Vols/Bkup ; then echo error...; fi`. Learn to use `set -vx` (or at least `set -x`) to see the debug/trace of your code as it executes. `$?` is the return status of the last executed command. `0` for good, Not `0` indicates error. Good luck. P.S. Very good "selfie" ;->

Comment: You can also use **compound statements** for error checking: `cp /Volumes/Documents/criticalfile.txt /Volumes/BackUp/ || { echo "[Error] copy failed!" 1>&2 && exit 1; }` Not a replacement for `if ... else ... fi`, but for short commands, it makes short concise code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
```

instead of

```
 if [ "?" != 0 ]; then
```

Let say I want to copy a file but i don't know if I will get an error. I use the below command

```
cp -f /root/Desktop/my_new_file */root/t
```

definitely this will give me an error because copying to "*/root/t" is not possible.

I can check this by using the following codes

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -f /root/Desktop/my_new_file */root/t
if [ "$?" = 0 ];then
echo "No error"
else
echo "We have  error!"
fi
```

MY OUTPUT (Note the condition is working)

```
cp: cannot create regular file `*/root/t': No such file or directory
We have  error
```

Now let say I want to copy a file to a possible location like

```
cp -f /root/Desktop/my_new_file /root/t
```

I will get no error from cp command

OUTPUT

```
No error
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `if [ "?" != 0 ]` is not correct.
You're looking for `if [ $? != 0 ]` instead.

But an even better way:

```
if ! cp /Volumes/Documents/criticalfile.txt /Volumes/BackUp/
then 
    echo "[Error] copy failed!" >&2 
    exit 1 
fi
```

I also dropped the 1 from `1>&2`, as `>&2` is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

fix your code.

```
cp /Volumes/Documents/criticalfile.txt /Volumes/BackUp/ > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then 
    echo "[Error] copy failed!"
    exit 1 
fi
```

one liner

```
cp infile /Volumes/BackUp/ > /dev/null 2>&1 || echo "[Error] copy failed!"
```